# Laravel - Hashids

Tags: php, apache, laravel

Since I have installed [this package](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids)
, I have an issue which append randomly : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I can't debug him because he doesn't provide any errors logs at all. And if I try to `dd()` some part of the code, it will work perfectly.

Some people are talking about setting up the flag in the .htaccess :

> ```
> php_flag opcache.enable Off
> ```

.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    php_flag opcache.enable Off

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Everythings is really weird :

```
dd($this->hashidsManager->encode(2141421)) --> work
dd($user->id) --> work
dd($this->hashidsManager->encode($user->id)) --> doesn't work
```